# Failed installing 'tomcat 7' service

Tags: windows-services, tomcat7

I tried to install Tomcat as a service with the `service.bat` file in `CATALINA_HOME\bin\` but it ends just showing the error:

> Failed installing 'tomcat 7' service

Any clue?

Comment: Try to run it as "Administrator", perhaps that helps. Or have a look at the Event Viewer.

Comment: Tried as Admin, same error. Tried Event Viewer, error `Service not running`. Tried to run the service, warning `Windows could not start the Windows Event Log service on Local Computer. Error 5: Access is denied`.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Finally, it was easier.

First, try to remove any other Tomcat service already installed `service.bat remove`.

Second, install the service `service.bat install` and voilà!

Thanks for your time.

Comment: saved my day, remove and install did the job even if i only failed in installing before doing remove

Answer (score 2):

It appears to be a permission issue, where are you running the installation from, I had this issue when trying to install from `"C:\tomcat"`, I ended up installing the MSI which runs ok.

Comment: I have it under `C:\Program Files\Apache Software\Tomcat 7.0.22\bin\service.bat` it is supposed I have admin privileges, but I'll take a look at it...

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I finally found the error was due to port in use error. After changing the port `#` in `server.xml`, ran `service.bat remove` and then `service.bat install`. This fixed the issue.

Comment: this should be a comment