# Access is denied when installing Tomcat 7 as service

Tags: java, jvm, tomcat7

I'm trying to install Apache Tomcat 7 as a service in Windows 7. I'm executing the following command inside my Tomcat bin folder:

```
CALL service.bat install 10080
```

But I'm getting following error:

```
Installing the service '10080' ...
Using CATALINA_HOME:    "D:\ASI Installables\apache-tomcat-7.0.32"
Using CATALINA_BASE:    "D:\ASI Installables\apache-tomcat-7.0.32"
Using JAVA_HOME:        "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_21"
Using JRE_HOME:         "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_21\jre"
Using JVM:              "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_21\jre\bin\server\jvm.dll"
Access is denied.
Failed to install serviceFailed installing '10080' service
```

I'm logged in as Administrator to the user, still I'm getting this error.

Comment: [Refernce](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9626804/failed-installing-tomcat-7-service)

Comment: I tried to remove the previous tomcat service installed and its giving me 

[SC] OpenService FAILED 5:

Access is denied.

Comment: This is not a programming question - for questions about administering server software you may have more luck posting on http://serverfault.com.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure `10080` is a good name for a service (in fact, I'm not sure whether Windows allows such names). Try `Tomcat10080` instead.

The next thing is that you need to be Administrator to do this. I'm not sure what you mean by "I'm logged in as Administrator to the user" but since the command fails, you must be doing something wrong. The [Tomcat documentation says](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/windows-service-howto.html#Installing_services): Log in as `Adminstrator` and run `service.bat --User=account` to install the service to use `account`.

The [tool `runas` might be useful in this context](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/runas.mspx?mfr=true).

I also suggest to put this into a script because I found that after a while, you will need to do this again and then, you will have forgotten what you did exactly.

Answer (score 0):

Even if you are logged in as admin does not mean you have all admin rights, you need to run your bat as administratior, check this [answer](https://superuser.com/a/74565) for further help.